# How to tag a page in facebook post using Request call android with Facebook SDK

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, tagging

My requirement is to post a facebook share an image with a text message which includeS a tag to a certain page in facebook. Have anyone done something like this ??

Please find the code I have used for posting the image and text. I would like to have a tag to a page in facebook in between the message text. Would it be possible to tag a page in the post ?

Ex: I am selling a Pen via MyApp. Are you interested ?

(This MyApp should open the facebook page of my application, lets say https://www.facebook.com/MyApp)

private void postPhoto() throws FileNotFoundException {

```
    if (hasPublishPermission()) {
        Bitmap image  = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.icon);

        if (imagePath.size()>0) {
            image = imagePath.get(0);
        }

        Request request = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(Session.getActiveSession(),image, new Request.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                showPublishResult(getString(R.string.fb_photo_post), response.getGraphObject(), response.getError());
            }
        });

        Bundle params = request.getParameters();
        String post_text = getResources().getString(R.string.fb_post_text_head) + editText.getText().toString() 
                + getResources().getString(R.string.fb_post_text_tail);
        params.putString("message", post_text);
        request.setParameters(params);

        request.executeAsync();

        request.setCallback(new Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Utils.printLog(activity,"onCompleted >>>> "+ response);
            }
        });

    } else {
        pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_PHOTO;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not allowed to prefill the message. The user need to manually type every single character